# How to use Joomla website clone in PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, joomla

I am new in Joomla & PhoneGap,

A lots of tools are available for cloing of Joomla site, but I want download any free clone  of Joomla website and use that clone in PhoneGap, ie the same structure, outlook & flow.

I study a lots on google, but i am little bit confuse between Joomla Template and clone. 
I know that to execute PHP Script we have to write Web-services.

So where we can download and use joomla clone in PhoneGap.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why to use a joomla website in a phonegap app, you will have to writte a more targeted website. Joomla is not the best mix for this. As already said you can't run php on the device.

Comment: Can we integrate any CMS (Joomla,Wordpress, etc...) with PhoneGap ?

Comment: AFAIK no, beside that it will be a overhead to do that for the mobile device. Check CMS for phongap cordova app

Comment: You can serve content to the app using json-api like stuff with wordpress, suppose joomla also have that possibility. But if you just want to run your app pasting all your website into the app no, be aware wordpress like systems use databases. On phonegap you can have sqlite dbs or non-sqls dbs which are morr covenient for apps, so if you want to have a quick and dirty app you are going to face more problems IMHO..not sure want to achieve..

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge you cann't right away use Joomla in PhoneGap. PhoneGap itself is not able to run PHP applications. But you can use PhoneGap app to run as a web site with fair amount of code modifications.

If you want to execute PHP in PhoneGap you will have to make a AJAX call to get the work done. You can use the returned results in your PhoneGap application.